# CodeIgniter: Use HTTP & XML API to send message

Tags: php, api, codeigniter

I've purchased a online bulk sms account ,where we find a http and a xml api for sending sms to any number -

```
  http://yourURL/api/smsapi.aspx?username=yourUsername&password=yourPassword&to=9xxxxxxxxx,8xxxxxxxxx,7xxxxxxxxx&from=yourSenderId&message=Your message content.
```

and xml api is-

```
<xml>
     <account>
          <username>yourUsername</username>
          <password>yourPassword</password>
     </account>
     <sender>
          <from>yourSenderId</from>
     </sender>
     <message>
          <text>Your message content.</text>
     </message>
     <unicode>
          <code>1</code>
     </unicode>
     <mobilenumber>
          <to>9XXXXXXXXX</to>
          <to>8XXXXXXXXX</to>
          <to>7XXXXXXXXX</to>
     </mobilenumber>
</xml>
```

but we create our school management system project in codeignitor php , so i search in Google but not find ..how we use it with our project?? please give any helping links or something about help??

Answer (score 0):

as you see in the URL: **smsapi.aspx**

Aspx = Microsoft .NET

That mean you need a Microsoft-Server (ISS) and install the script on this. Codeigniter is PHP-Server and have nothing to to with this!